# Multiple joins in Django model

Tags: python, sql, django

I have Django models as:

```
class Species(models.Model):
    species_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Species ID', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=100)



class Status(models.Model):
    species_id = models.ForeignKey(Species, db_column='Species ID', primary_key=True)
    protected = models.NullBooleanField(db_column='Protected')

class Images(models.Model):
    species_id = models.ForeignKey('Species', db_column='Species ID')
    url = models.CharField(db_column='URL', max_length=719)
```

Is there any way I can perform the following SQL query without using raw SQL.

```
SELECT Name, URL FROM Images i 
INNER JOIN Species s USING (`Species ID`) 
INNER JOIN Status st USING (`Species ID`) 
WHERE `st`.`Protected` = TRUE
```

Comment: in the `Species` Model, you don't have to manually create a `species_id` field, unless you have strong reasons to do so. Django does this automatically for you. Then, in the other 2 models, only have the fields called `species`. And you can refer to the id of `Species` as `species_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would refactor your code:

```
class Species(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=100)

class Status(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey(Species, db_column='Species ID', primary_key=True)
    protected = models.NullBooleanField(db_column='Protected')

class Images(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey('Species', db_column='Species ID')
    url = models.CharField(db_column='URL', max_length=719)
```

Then I would do:

```
protected_species = Status.objects
                    .filter(protected=True)
                    .values_list('species_id', flat=True)
Images.objects.filter(species_id__in=protected_species)
              .values('url','species__name')
```

But as @Maxime Lorant said, I think your Models are dazzled.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your models a little bit, you could do something like this:

```py
images = Images.objects.filter(species__status__protected=True)
```

**Updated models**:

```
class Species(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Status(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey('Species', primary_key=True)
    protected = models.NullBooleanField()

class Images(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey('Species')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=719)
```

Comment: `Images.objects.filter(species__status__protected=True).values('url', species_id__name')`

Comment: you forgot about the ForeignKey you was talking about

Answer (score 0):

Your database structure is kind of broken first. I suppose there is only 1 status per `Species` object, so you don't need to have 3 models there. With 2 models you can do the following:

```
class Species(models.Model):
    species_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Species ID', primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=100)
    protected = models.NullBooleanField(db_column='Protected')


class Images(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey('Species', db_column='Species ID')
    url = models.CharField(db_column='URL', max_length=719)

# query
data = Images.objects.filter(species__protected=True).values('url', 'species__name')
```

Comment: The thing is not all `Species` have `Status`.

Comment: @smaske You are using a [`NullBooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.NullBooleanField), so you can use the `None` value by default is a species does not have a status.